# ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value).share is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hello I have been searching for an answer about this error I'm getting. I cannot seem to figure this out, I have read a lot of posts similar but none the same. I just updated from `angular 4/ rxjs "5.0.0-beta.12"` to `angular 7 /rxjs 6.3.3` I have been running into this error

> ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value).share is not a function
>       at new ProgressBarService (progressbar.service.ts:21)
>       at _createClass (core.js:19827)
>       at _createProviderInstance (core.js:19801)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:19765)
>       at _createClass (core.js:19837)
>       at *createProviderInstance (core.js:19801)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:19765)
>       at NgModuleRef*.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.js:20473)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:20844)
>       at createClass (core.js:20720)

which i have found to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';`
and add the following code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';  // added method
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';           // added method
```

but neither seem to work. does anyone have sugestions?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#backwards-compatibility

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJS v6 has new [import statements](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#import-paths) (see section 2 in the link).

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, debounceTime, share } from 'rxjs/operators';  // added method
```

Comment: the error is coming from share function. share is also needed to be included.

Answer (score 0):

the import style on rxjs 6 is different. Besides OP's error is coming from `share` function.

your imports should be (including `share` function)

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, share, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Don't you see that you're answering exactly the same as @DeborahK?

Comment: the error message is coming from `share` function. not from the map and debounceTime

Comment: I see, in that case why didn't you comment it in @DeborahK's answer? from your answer it is very unclear